# White flash when navigating between pages in React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm building a React Native app using the react-navigation library for screen navigation. When I navigate between pages, I'm seeing a white flash or flicker for about a second, which looks bad and disrupts the user experience.

Can anyone suggest any solutions or best practices to minimize or eliminate the white flash when navigating between pages in a React Native app? I'm open to using custom transition animations, libraries, or any other approaches that can help improve the user experience.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can offer!

I've tried setting headerShown: false for the navigationOptions in my screens, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import Details from "../components/screens/Details";
import Home from "../components/screens/Home";
const screens = {
  Default: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
  Details: {
    screen: Details,
    navigationOptions: {
    headerShown: false,
  },
},
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator (screens)
export default createAppContainer (HomeStack);
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the 4th version of react-navigation? Its possible that using  the latest version will resolve this issue